# Audio classification with neural networks

Tags: neural-networks

I would like to classify bird species from audio recordings. To do this, I am calculating a number of features in a frequency spectrum: I take certain block size (say, 2048 samples) and compute mel spectrum coefficients, spectral rolloff, LSF coefficients, spectral flux etc. - they make together a very good description of the sound.

A bird call typically lasts a few seconds, meaning it consists (with 16 kHz sampling) of easily 30000 samples. Can you provide some hints on what architecture I could use to tackle the problem?

I was thinking of the following:

1. Calculate features for the 2048 block size.
2. Calculate next block with half overlap (1024).
3. Repeat the process until I have captured 2 seconds of features. If in a single block I get 50 features, then the complete vector would have roughly 1500 features (because of the 30k samples in a typical call).
4. The 1500 features will constitute my input to the ANN. It covers 2 seconds of a recording. With half of overlap I would then take next 2 seconds and repeat the process.

I was then thinking of ANN with 1-2 hidden layers, likely much smaller than the input vector. What do you think?

As an alternative I am considering making a spectrogram and working with CNNs.

Comment: I think [LSTMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory) are the way too go. Secondly, you say 'compute spectrum coefficients, spectral rolloff, etc.' ( I have no clue what some of those things are'. But why do you NEED to compute these? You can let the neural network figure that out through backpropagation. 

With LSTM, you can sample `x` samples every time you input. Just check which `x` works best for you.

Comment: LSTM could be a way to go if I were using raw data as you are suggesting, as then it would be a proper time series. Why not using raw data then? Because then I would have huge input vector which would make my network very expensive to train. Besides, one of the points of using ANN is that they can create features for us. However, in this case I am able to build features myself.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar project for auto-tagging of audio files I used spectrograms and worked with CNNs as, according to my research, these choices resulted in many  state of the art models.
I have uploaded my code on [GitHub](https://github.com/emarkou/Audio-auto-tagging) accompanied by a detailed description of the whole process, if it helps.